# squid rule S00864 does not exist

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

the rule Correctness - Integer multiply of result of integer remainder notes that "This rule is deprecated, use S00864 instead. ", but S00864 does not exist.

Comment: I had to figure out that this was impacting findbugs rules, but this is now fixed : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-findbugs/commit/397138d6edb438ee8f83f92e986a61298599a2b7 and https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-findbugs/commit/f103d8d664fade4247248b9fcbc01239d024061e and should be available with next release of findbugs-plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it might be a typo in the description, since S864 exists, and is about operator precedence. The link that you clicked on for finding S00864, update the URL to remove the 00 to just S864 to see the rule.